# FTP Disconnect after PASV

Tags: iis-7, ftp, windows-server-2008, amazon-ec2

This is FileZilla connecting to an FTP server on a Windows Server 2008 machine in the Amazon EC2 cloud. I can't figure out why it keeps kicking me.

```
Command:    OPTS UTF8 ON
Response:   200 OPTS UTF8 command successful - UTF8 encoding now ON.
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is current directory.
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I.
Command:    PASV
Error:  Disconnected from server: ECONNABORTED - Connection aborted
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. In order to resolve,

> In Filezilla go to Edit -> settings. On settings page click on FTP on the left and choose Active on the right. Hit OK and then connect

*NOTE: Unlike `Amazon EC2` in your case, I had my VM on `Azure`. Just make sure, you have enabled port 21 as i did while configuring my VM's FTP endpoints on Azure portal. This step may be different in AWS*

Comment: Additionally you could forward the ports for PASV -http://serverfault.com/questions/270745/why-does-ftp-passive-mode-require-a-port-range-as-opposed-to-only-one-port

Answer (score 0):

Have you given the FTP user permissions on the directory you're pointing it at?

Comment: The FTP user is actually an IIS Manager - not a real user, so I can't give it any more permissions than IIS does